# What do these prior distributions mean?

Tags: bayesian, interpretation, prior, intuition

Suppose we have a prior distribution of $$\pi_1(\theta)=k\theta^{k-1},$$ and we have another of $$\pi_2(\theta)=k(1-\theta)^{k-1}.$$ Intuitively, what do the two different distributions mean / represent?

I understand that the summarise the beliefs of the tester before and after the test, but I don't understand specifically what these ones mean. Are they not both very much the same, since if $\theta\in(0,1)$, then so is $(1-\theta)$, and the only "difference" is that one is analogous to probability of throwing heads, while the other is analogous to throwing tails - by symmetry aren't both these prior distributions "the same"?

I'd like to understand what $k$ and $\theta$ represent, and also what is significant about the power of $k-1$ - what makes this different to, say, an exponential function?

---

Note: both have $\theta\in(0,1)$, $k>1$ is a constant, and is discrete (an integer).

The likelihood is a binomial - $f(x|\theta)={k\choose x} \theta^x (1-\theta)^{k-x}$ - and is applied to $n$ i.i.d. random variables, so the overall likelihood is $$f(\vec x|\theta)=\left(\prod_{i=1}^n {{k}\choose x_i}\right)\theta^{\sum x_i}(1-\theta)^{nk-\sum x_i}$$

Comment: I agree with you. They are complementary priors.

Comment: @Bey What are complementary priors? I haven't heard of these before. What do they mean about the different initial beliefs of the testers? Or are the two beliefs not different?

Comment: It's not a technical term, they are expressing the same idea different ways.

Comment: Is $k$ continuous or does it take discrete values like - 2, 3, 4, etc? Also could you be more elaborate on what $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ represent. Posterior = prior $\times$ likelihood, so you also have to tell what is the likelihood function, you haven't mentioned that here.

Comment: @ShishirPandey I have edited to include this

Comment: @Xi'an I just meant that I understand that about priors and posteriors in general - that they represent beliefs before and after a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The priors are beta distributions:
$$\begin{align} \operatorname{beta}(\theta\mid k,1) &= \theta^{k-1} (1-\theta)^{1-1} / B(k,1) \\ &= \theta^{k-1} / (1/k) \\ &= k \theta^{k-1} \end{align}$$
Typically that's interpreted as having previously observed $k$ successes and $1$ failure. The other prior is just $\operatorname{beta}(\theta\mid 1,k)$.